# Float left to align elements horizontal

Tags: html, css

I have left and right arrow buttons on both sides of the main content.
I set buttons as `input type="button"` and turn them into `block` element by `display:block`
and they all have `float:left`.

The thing is that they are placed in a desired position but with other elements on a different line like navigation menu, the buttons get pushed up/down to another row.

Can someone please take a look at my working sample here? [JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/anuCAbI/3/edit)

Comment: What do you mean by "they break"? That's not descriptive enough to provide a reasonable amount of help. If you're talking about them not being centered with the other content, that has to do with the margins and padding on all of the elements.

Comment: I've provided my working sample which should be descriptive enough of what I meant by "break". I am not after centering them. I simply want to position them as `<< content >>`

Comment: They're doing that. If in your jsbin example you turn off everything except for Output, you'll see everything on the same line. Horizontal space is limited; if you have too much there, it will wrap.

Comment: Thanks. I only checked it with a small output screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not descriptive enough. I think you mean that the divs moves up to be in-line with menu. That is what I observed. I modified your code so that divs will start after menu and << button.

```
<ul class="nav-step">
    <li class="active">1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
  <input class="left" type="button" value="<<" />
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  <div class="pg-wrapper">
    <div class="current" id="pg1">
      <label>First</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div id="pg2">
      <label>Second</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div id="pg3">
      <label>Third</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Observe :

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Hope this will be of some help.

Comment: Thanks. Your observation on my issue is correct and `clear:both` on a new div element in between solves the problem. Is there any other way around than inserting a blank div? like using `:after` `:before`?

Comment: I think `#wrapper:after{
  content: " ";
    display: block;
  clear:both;
}` would do. Not sure though. Also, I would not use it because of browser compatibility issues.